# How to store all files universally in memory (variable) Python

Tags: python, file

Essentially, I would want to be able to go through a folder with text files, jpg files, csv files, png files, any kind of file, and be able to load it into memory as some kind of object. When necessary, I would then like to be able to save it and create an instance on disk. This would need to work for any kind of file type.

I would create a class that would contain the file data itself as well as metadata, but that is not necessary for my question.

Is this possible ,and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: You can read files as bytes. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `open('filename.ext', 'r+b')` will work for anything, and supports both reading and writing - as long as you don't care about interpreting the file in question in-memory. Combine this with `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()` to find the files.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. I have used FID = open('filename.ext', 'r+b') and then FID.write() and FID.read() to write/read the files.